# using bundles in existing webforms project

Tags: c#, webforms, bundling-and-minification

I have an existing web forms project that is now using .net 4.5.

Using nuget I added the reference to system.web.omtimization.

I then placed in the header and also tried near my footer:

```
 <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/CaseReview") %>
```

Also I add the following to global.asax:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

I am getting:
The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context

I can use bundling with webforms yeah?

If so what am I doing wrong/not doing?

Answer (score 10):

Seems this did the job:

```
<%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/CaseReview") %>
```

Comment: You could also add a namespace entry in the pages element of your web.config

Comment: Yeah true, I will get around to that!

Comment: I also added this line at the top of the aspx page `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>` just below the Page directive.

Comment: I was annoyed of this for so long :) finally a solution that works. +1